# Correct way for Bussnes logic in AC

Tags: php, oop, yii2

Im new in yii. I have question about Active record and bussnes logic in models.
I have model and controller:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Photos extends ActiveRecord 
{

}
```

Controller:

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Photos;

class PhotosController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
       $photos = Photos::find()
            ->where(['userid' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
            ->all();
       return $this->render('index', ['photos' => $photos]);
    }
}
```

I want do that in other way:

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Photos extends ActiveRecord 
{
    public function findOneById($id) 
    {
        return Photos::findOne($id);
    }   
}
```

And Controller:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;
use app\models\Photos;

class PhotosController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $photos = Photos::findByUserId(Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
        return $this->render('index', ['photos' => $photos]);
    }
}
```

What is correct way to do this?
Im about fat model, and tiny controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is more true, controllers should be small and all business logic should be rendered in models or functional classes